# multithreading server store messages from clients and print them after x seconds

Tags: c, multithreading, networking, server

I am trying to create a server that listening messages from clients in a thread and after x seconds to close the main thread and print the messages from all clients from the main thread.
Can you tell me what I am doing wrong ?

main()

```
/*Accept connection and open thread for every connection*/
while(1) 
{
    printf("Waiting for conections \n");

     /*The accept call blocks until a connection is found*/
    check_return((client_sok =
                    accept(server_sok, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr,  
                    (socklen_t*)&len_serv_addr)), "Server: Accept error");

    pthread_t t;
    int *pclient = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *pclient = client_sok;
    
    pthread_create(&t, NULL, client_connection, pclient);
    sleep(10);
    /* print received messages */
    if (total_messages)
    {
        printf("Server: \n%s\n", total_messages);
        free(total_messages);
        total_messages = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Server: No received messages\n");
    }
```

thread function

```
void * client_connection(void * client_socket )
{
        printf("Threading\n");
        int new_client_sok = *((int*)client_socket);
        free(client_socket);
        char buffer[BUFLEN];

        check_return(read(new_client_sok, message_client, BUFLEN),"Server: Error reading msg");
        
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);  
        char *message = malloc(sizeof(message_client));
        strcpy(message, "Server:");
        strcat(message, message_client);
        strcpy(buffer,message);
        free(message);
        printf("%s\n", message);
        append_message(buffer);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
       
        check_return(send(new_client_sok, ACK, strlen(ACK)+1, 0),"Server: Error sending msg");
        close(new_client_sok);
        pthread_exit(NULL);

}
```

Comment: This code has several problems, but what is the problem that you observe?

Comment: hi, first of all try to explain the problem you run into. For us readers, it is hard to debug if we don't know what is not working. Your question lacks clarity, and I don't understand what you are trying to do with this code. Also as a side note it is good practice to use malloc() and free() in the same scope (in your case, the main function). That will avoid you nasty memory problems in your future programs